# Unsupported URL with post data from IOS to backend service

Tags: javascript, objective-c, node.js, swift, webrtc

I want to use webrtc in an IOS (Swift) project. I find so much difficulties to implement it properly. So I searched for an library so I can get how it is implemented to do it later myself.

I found this project:
https://github.com/sushilthe/webrtc-ios-swift

It works fine with https://apprtc.appspot.com. But it is making a POST? request when you want to join a room:

---

Base url:
https://apprtc.appspot.com/

Part that is appended to the base:

static NSString *kARDRoomServerRegisterFormat =
    @"%@/join/%@";

Result:

https://apprtc.appspot.com/join/'roomnr'

---

I have build a server with some resources from the internet:

```
$(document).ready(function() { //wait for DOM to be ready for JS execution
    easyrtc.setVideoDims(1280, 768);
    easyrtc.easyApp('vcdemo', 'self', ['peer'], connectSuccess, failureCallback); //connect to easyrtc app; initiate media sources and elements
});

//global state variables
var myEasyrtcId; //id of client in the signaling framework

//global functions
var connectSuccess = function(easyrtcid) { //join room as defined by "room" parameter in URL
    myEasyrtcId = easyrtcid;
    console.log('Connect successful. My id is ' + myEasyrtcId + '.');
    var room = decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]room=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)'). //retrieve room name from URL
        exec(location.search) || [, ""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null;
    console.log('join room: ' + room);
    easyrtc.joinRoom(room, null, joinSuccess, failureCallback);
};



var failureCallback = function(errorCode, errorMsg) { //log error
    console.log(errorCode);
    console.log(errorMsg);
};

var joinSuccess = function(roomName) { //listen for peers joining the room
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('successfully joined room: ' + roomName);
        var peers = easyrtc.getRoomOccupantsAsArray(roomName) || []; //get list of client connected to room
        console.log('peers: ' + peers);
        var peersLength = peers.length;
        if (peersLength > 2) { //support only 1-1 video conferences
            alert('The meeting room is already full. ' +
                'Only the two peers connecting first will be allowed access.');
        } else if(peersLength === 1) { //if no other peer is connected
            console.log('waiting for peer to connect...');
        } else if(peers[0] != myEasyrtcId) {//get peer id
            easyrtc.call(peers[0]);
        } else {
            easyrtc.call(peers[1]);
        }
    }, 100);
};
```

This works perfect in chrome and firefox via this url:

localhost:8080/?room=123

And I can connect to that stream when I reuse that room number. Perfect!

So I thought I can implement that in the app, I have changed the serverHostUrl to: `client?.serverHostUrl = "192.168.1.59:8080"`

And the other variable:

```
static NSString *kARDRoomServerRegisterFormat = @"%@/?room=%@";
```

But I get an error when it try's to submit the url:

```
Client Connecting
2016-10-17 19:24:51.151795 WebRTC iOS Swift[3944:1036130] Registering with room server.
2016-10-17 19:24:51.151900 WebRTC iOS Swift[3944:1036130] url = 192.168.1.59:8080/?room=123
2016-10-17 19:24:51.207496 WebRTC iOS Swift[3944:1036130] Error posting data: unsupported URL
Client Disconnected
```

I have searched a few hours why this is happening. But I can't find the problem. Thank you very much!

EDIT

The Code where it goes wrong:

The roomURL is: 192.168.1.59:8080/?room=123 at that moment.

```
  [NSURLConnection sendAsyncPostToURL:roomURL
                             withData:nil
                    completionHandler:^(BOOL succeeded, NSData *data) {
    ARDAppClient *strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (!succeeded) {
      NSError *error = [self roomServerNetworkError];
      [strongSelf.delegate appClient:strongSelf didError:error];
      completionHandler(nil);
      return;
    }
    ARDRegisterResponse *response =
        [ARDRegisterResponse responseFromJSONData:data];
    completionHandler(response);
  }];
```

Comment: Compare the NSLogged absolute URL on the successful and unsuccessful attempts.  What's different?  The scheme maybe?  Like http ://192...?  Also, see what happens when you paste the local host ip URL into a browser.  You'll have an easier time inspecting the response with chrome dev tools

Comment: @danh, the url before submitting is: 192.168.1.59:8080/?room=123

Comment: No scheme?  See whether you need a scheme.